FileNotFoundError when attempting to use plt.savefig to save an EPS file
The error has been stated here: Python : FileNotFoundError [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified , subprocess.py:1582
I wanna to know how to set shell=True when running a command, instead of changing the __init__(..., shell=True, ...) in subprocess.py.
For instance, I run the command python plot.py and get the error as follows:
File "...\.conda\envs\pinns-env\lib\subprocess.py", line 957, in _execute_child     
    startupinfo)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

how can I fix it?
I have searched for many solutions, all of which only tell me to set shell=True, but I don't know how.

The error message:
<ipython-input-5-f7c8e3bd400a> in <module>
     39 ax.set_ylabel('$y$')
     40 ax.set_title('Vorticity', fontsize = 10)
---> 41 savefig("./figures/vorticity")

d:\Learning\Graduate\PINNs-code\Utilities\plotting.py in savefig(filename, crop)
     52 #        plt.savefig('{}.pgf'.format(filename), bbox_inches='tight', pad_inches=0)
     53         plt.savefig('{}.pdf'.format(filename), bbox_inches='tight', pad_inches=0)
---> 54         plt.savefig('{}.eps'.format(filename), bbox_inches='tight', pad_inches=0)
     55     else:
     56 #        plt.savefig('{}.pgf'.format(filename))

c:\Users\zjuer\.conda\envs\pinns-env\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py in savefig(*args, **kwargs)
    686 def savefig(*args, **kwargs):
    687     fig = gcf()
--> 688     res = fig.savefig(*args, **kwargs)
    689     fig.canvas.draw_idle()   # need this if 'transparent=True' to reset colors
    690     return res

c:\Users\zjuer\.conda\envs\pinns-env\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\figure.py in savefig(self, fname, frameon, transparent, **kwargs)
   2095             self.set_frameon(frameon)
   2096 
-> 2097         self.canvas.print_figure(fname, **kwargs)
   2098 
   2099         if frameon:

c:\Users\zjuer\.conda\envs\pinns-env\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backend_bases.py in print_figure(self, filename, dpi, facecolor, edgecolor, orientation, format, bbox_inches, **kwargs)
   2073                     orientation=orientation,
   2074                     bbox_inches_restore=_bbox_inches_restore,
-> 2075                     **kwargs)
   2076             finally:
   2077                 if bbox_inches and restore_bbox:

c:\Users\zjuer\.conda\envs\pinns-env\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_ps.py in print_eps(self, outfile, *args, **kwargs)
    919 
    920     def print_eps(self, outfile, *args, **kwargs):
--> 921         return self._print_ps(outfile, 'eps', *args, **kwargs)
    922 
    923     def _print_ps(self, outfile, format, *args,

c:\Users\zjuer\.conda\envs\pinns-env\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_ps.py in _print_ps(self, outfile, format, papertype, dpi, facecolor, edgecolor, orientation, *args, **kwargs)
    944             self._print_figure_tex(outfile, format, dpi, facecolor, edgecolor,
    945                                    orientation, isLandscape, papertype,
--> 946                                    **kwargs)
    947         else:
    948             self._print_figure(outfile, format, dpi, facecolor, edgecolor,

c:\Users\zjuer\.conda\envs\pinns-env\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_ps.py in _print_figure_tex(self, outfile, format, dpi, facecolor, edgecolor, orientation, isLandscape, papertype, metadata, dryrun, bbox_inches_restore, **kwargs)
   1334                     or rcParams['text.usetex']):
   1335                 gs_distill(tmpfile, isEPSF, ptype=papertype, bbox=bbox,
-> 1336                            rotated=psfrag_rotated)
   1337             elif rcParams['ps.usedistiller'] == 'xpdf':
   1338                 xpdf_distill(tmpfile, isEPSF, ptype=papertype, bbox=bbox,

c:\Users\zjuer\.conda\envs\pinns-env\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_ps.py in gs_distill(tmpfile, eps, ptype, bbox, rotated)
   1469 
   1470     gs_exe = ps_backend_helper.gs_exe
-> 1471     if ps_backend_helper.supports_ps2write: # gs version >= 9
   1472         device_name = "ps2write"
   1473     else:

c:\Users\zjuer\.conda\envs\pinns-env\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_ps.py in supports_ps2write(self)
     92         True if the installed ghostscript supports ps2write device.
     93         """
---> 94         return self.gs_version[0] >= 9
     95 
     96 ps_backend_helper = PsBackendHelper()

c:\Users\zjuer\.conda\envs\pinns-env\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_ps.py in gs_version(self)
     76 
     77         s = subprocess.Popen(
---> 78             [self.gs_exe, "--version"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
     79         pipe, stderr = s.communicate()
     80         ver = pipe.decode('ascii')

c:\Users\zjuer\.conda\envs\pinns-env\lib\subprocess.py in __init__(self, args, bufsize, executable, stdin, stdout, stderr, preexec_fn, close_fds, shell, cwd, env, universal_newlines, startupinfo, creationflags, restore_signals, start_new_session, pass_fds)
    674                                 c2pread, c2pwrite,
    675                                 errread, errwrite,
--> 676                                 restore_signals, start_new_session)
    677         except:
    678             # Cleanup if the child failed starting.

c:\Users\zjuer\.conda\envs\pinns-env\lib\subprocess.py in _execute_child(self, args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds, pass_fds, cwd, env, startupinfo, creationflags, shell, p2cread, p2cwrite, c2pread, c2pwrite, errread, errwrite, unused_restore_signals, unused_start_new_session)
    955                                          env,
    956                                          cwd,
--> 957                                          startupinfo)
    958             finally:
    959                 # Child is launched. Close the parent's copy of those pipe

FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] 系统找不到指定的文件。


The full code:

data_vort = scipy.io.loadmat('../Data/cylinder_nektar_t0_vorticity.mat')

x_vort = data_vort\['x'\]
y_vort = data_vort\['y'\]
w_vort = data_vort\['w'\]
modes = np.asscalar(data_vort\['modes'\])
nel = np.asscalar(data_vort\['nel'\])

xx_vort = np.reshape(x_vort, (modes+1,modes+1,nel), order = 'F')
yy_vort = np.reshape(y_vort, (modes+1,modes+1,nel), order = 'F')
ww_vort = np.reshape(w_vort, (modes+1,modes+1,nel), order = 'F')

box_lb = np.array(\[1.0, -2.0\])
box_ub = np.array(\[8.0, 2.0\])

fig, ax = newfig(1.0, 1.2)
ax.axis('off')

####### Row 0: Vorticity ##################  
gs0 = gridspec.GridSpec(1, 2)
gs0.update(top=1-0.06, bottom=1-2/4 + 0.12, left=0.0, right=1.0, wspace=0)
ax = plt.subplot(gs0\[:, :\])

for i in range(0, nel):
    h = ax.pcolormesh(xx_vort\[:,:,i\], yy_vort\[:,:,i\], ww_vort\[:,:,i\], cmap='seismic',shading='gouraud',  vmin=-3, vmax=3)
divider = make_axes_locatable(ax)
cax = divider.append_axes("right", size="5%", pad=0.05)
fig.colorbar(h, cax=cax)

ax.plot(\[box_lb\[0\],box_lb\[0\]\],\[box_lb\[1\],box_ub\[1\]\],'k',linewidth = 1)
ax.plot(\[box_ub\[0\],box_ub\[0\]\],\[box_lb\[1\],box_ub\[1\]\],'k',linewidth = 1)
ax.plot(\[box_lb\[0\],box_ub\[0\]\],\[box_lb\[1\],box_lb\[1\]\],'k',linewidth = 1)
ax.plot(\[box_lb\[0\],box_ub\[0\]\],\[box_ub\[1\],box_ub\[1\]\],'k',linewidth = 1)

ax.set_aspect('equal', 'box')
ax.set_xlabel('$x$')
ax.set_ylabel('$y$')
ax.set_title('Vorticity', fontsize = 10)
savefig("./figures/vorticity")


where the savefig is defined as follows:
def savefig(filename, crop = True):
if crop == True:
    #plt.savefig('{}.pgf'.format(filename), bbox_inches='tight', pad_inches=0)
    plt.savefig('{}.pdf'.format(filename), bbox_inches='tight', pad_inches=0)
    plt.savefig('{}.eps'.format(filename), bbox_inches='tight', pad_inches=0)
else:
    #plt.savefig('{}.pgf'.format(filename))
    plt.savefig('{}.pdf'.format(filename))
    plt.savefig('{}.eps'.format(filename))


Do you have GhostScript installed?  That's what it is looking for.

I have installed it, and I have tried it in my terminal.

Did you add the GhostScript directory to your PATH environment variable?
